# Encryption of database data

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption

Now I know this question has been asked many, many times regarding where to do encryption, what to encrypt and what to encrypt with.

Anyway, when it comes to encryption of data within the database I know I can use `AES_ENCRYPT()` with the fieldname and a given key, plus I can incorporate things like date and time, or even a key stored in a separate table.

The issue I, as well as probably others face, is that there seems to be a million different ways to do it with everyone having an opinion on each one.

Also when it comes to security I know it is best not to try and create your own security measures.

So, my question is: what is a good standard practise to follow?

I have no issue with using AES but is there an industry standard?

Comment: Let's see if I understood. The first half of the question (code included) is unrelated to it. You want to encrypt data in MySQL and are unsure about using `AES_ENCRYPT()` because you've read too many opinions, so you've decided you want some more? I suggest you edit the question, remove all the references to one-way hashing (since you want two-way encryption) and put it in specific terms that can make it answerable. What are your concrete worries about AES?

Comment: Okay, that's fair enough.

Comment: If you have a solid reason for encrypting the data in your database and you want MySQL to handle it automatically for you, then using `AES_ENCRYPT` is fine as it will handle intricate details behind initialization vectors etc. However, if you **don't** have a solid reason for encrypting your data on the database level (since you lose all the goodies that come with SQL while working with encrypted fields), then just don't do it and encrypt the traffic between your app and MySQL (which can also be handled automatically by MySQL).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some of this and therefore can describe a tradeoff.  There are a few implementation specific questions such as whether there are measures in place to make encryption of short values safe (and I don't know the answer to that on MySQL -- I know on PostgreSQL that issue being handled has significant performance costs).

Assuming a secure encryption implementation in the database (and performance vs security here is actually another big tradeoff), you have some fundamental issues with this in the db.

1. Once you are storing cyphertext in the db, you give up on your ability to search by that information using an index.
2. With aes_encrypt you pass your key in, in the query string.  This means that if the query is logged, the key is logged to.  Ensuring that does not happen can make troubleshooting a bit hard when things go wrong.
3. On the other hand you can build more advanced key management systems with appropriate subqueries, such that you can gracefully handle key roatation.

Handling key rotation with application-level encryption is harder than it is in the db.  But key disclosure in logs is a real issue that requires thinking things through.  If I could give advice, it would be to focus on *that* issue first and then solve whichever one of those problems you are more inclined to solve.

Comment: Storing ciphertext in the column does not give up the ability to search by index if the cipher is deterministic (i.e. always encrypts to the same ciphertext). You can encrypt the desired search value, and search an index of encrypted values.

Comment: In which case, if the encryption is reversible (we are talking AES here) that makes it vulnerable.

Comment: Well, all encryption is reversible. I think you mean, if patterns are recognizable, which does make it more vulnerable than random encryption. But, point taken.

Comment: By reversible encryption, I mean something like AES, and not a one-way hashing algorithm.

Comment: But even with one-way hashes that is why we use a salt.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. You can encrypt data deterministically, for example, AES ECB, and so to look in an index for "orange", you encrypt "orange" and search the index for a matching ciphertext. Where do you see hashes? I wrote "encrypt".